# Open URLs from CSV

Tags: ruby, csv, nokogiri

I am using Ruby 2.1.0p0 on Mac OS.

I'm parsing a CSV file and grabbing all the URLs, then using Nokogiri and OpenURI to scrape them which is where I'm getting stuck.

When I try to use an `each` loop to run through the URLs array, I get this error:

```
initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - URL (Errno::ENOENT)
```

When I manually create an array, and then run through it I get no error. I've tried `to_s`, `URI::encode`, and everything I could think of and find on Stack Overflow.

I can copy and paste the URL from the CSV or from the terminal after using `puts` on the array and it opens in my browser no problem. I try to open it with Nokogiri it's not happening.

Here's my code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'uri'
require 'csv'

    events = Array.new
    CSV.foreach('productfeed.csv') do |row|
        events.push URI::encode(row[0]).to_s

    end 


    events.each do |event|

        page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("#{event}")) 

        #eventually, going to find info on the page, and scrape it, but not there yet. 

        #something to show I didn't get an error
        puts "open = success"


    end
```

Please help! I am completely out of ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're processing the header row, where on of those values is literally `"URL"`. That's not a valid URI so `open-uri` won't touch it.

There's a `headers` option for the CSV module that will make use of the headers automatically. Try turning that on and referring to `row["URL"]`

Comment: BOOM! Works perfectly. Thank you so much. I really appreciate it. Please vote this guy up! I don't have enough reputation. :-(

Comment: @JacksonRiso you might not have enough rep to upvote (yet), but you should be able to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) (which will give you a little rep too).

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing the same thing and found it to work better using a text file.

Here is what I did.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#import webbrowser module and time module
import webbrowser
import time

#open text file as "dataFile" and verify there is data in said file
dataFile = open('/home/user/Desktop/urls.txt','r')
if dataFile > 1:
        print("Data file opened successfully")
else:
        print("!!!!NO DATA IN FILE!!!!")
        exit()

#read file line by line, remove any spaces/newlines, and open link in chromium-browser
for lines in dataFile:
        url = str(lines.strip())
        print("Opening " + url)
        webbrowser.get('chromium-browser').open_new_tab(url)

#close file and exit
print("Closing Data File")
dataFile.close()

#wait two seconds before printing "Data file closed".
#this is purely for visual effect.
time.sleep(2)
print("Data file closed")

#after opener has run, user is prompted to press enter key to exit.
raw_input("\n\nURL Opener has run. Press the enter key to exit.")

exit()
```

Hope this helps!